# How can I choose randomly a drawable resource (picture) and set it as a background of a button?

Tags: java, android

I'm new with Android and StackOverflow. I accept all kind of recommendations while learning how to post correctly. My native language is not English, so please be patient if I don't write well.

I am making a game and what I have to do is to set bakcground in a specific moment of the game; 6 ramdom picture from drawable resources should be picked to set to 12 buttons I have in the UI (each one of the 6 ramdom pictures should be set to two different buttons).

What I don't know to do is how to set the images ramdonly and how to know in which button they were set. Being honest, I don't know how to start with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Integer> drawables = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, 
      R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6);

List<Integer> buttons = Arrays.asList(R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, 
    R.id.btn4, R.id.btn5, R.id.bt6, R.id.btn7, R.id.btn8, R.id.btn9, 
    R.id.btn10, R.id.btn11, R.id.btn12);

private void setRandomBackground() {
    Collections.shuffle(drawables);
    Collections.shuffle(buttons);

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < drawables.size(); i++, j+=2) {
        findViewById(buttons.get(j))
                .setBackgroundResource(drawables.get(i));
        findViewById(buttons.get(j+1))
                .setBackgroundResource(drawables.get(i));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can set random images to one login button

```
Integer images[]={
                R.drawable.animlogo,
                R.drawable.ablogin,
                R.drawable.normalbtnbackground
        };

        Random r=new Random();
        loginbtn.setBackgroundColor(images[r.nextInt(3)]);
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Your code was useful for something else i had  to do with my project. Thanks.

Comment: hehe... ur welcome. i've also used this code in one of my project for offline exam, where i've to display questions in random order.